# Network manager: "Error: Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking."

Tags: networking, permissions, networkmanager, void-linux

Just installed Network Manager on Void Linux. I am unable to activate connections with my normal user: when i try to, nmcli returns `Error: Connection activation failed: Not authorized to control networking.` It works with root. According to the [void handbook](https://docs.voidlinux.org/config/network/networkmanager.html), it is necessary to add an user to the `network` group in order for it to be able to use it. But i get the same error after adding my user to that group and rebooting.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes, as stated in the last word of my question.

Comment: Sorry for being inattentive. No ideas then. Maybe you could switch to a distro which uses NM natively. E.g. in Fedora I'm not a member of any groups, yet I can manage NM just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the issue was not having `polkit` installed. After installing it, it now works as intended. Strangely, there is no mention of `polkit` in the NetworkManager page of Void's handbook, or in any other page except one about `libvirt`.